# Bash mkdir and subfolders

Tags: bash, mkdir, git-bash

Why I can't do something like this? `mkdir folder/subfolder/` in order to achive this I have to do:

```
mkdir folder
cd folder
mkdir subfolder
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It may be a duplicate, but this question is formulated much more straight-forward. +1

Answer (score 336, accepted):

You can:

```
mkdir -p folder/subfolder
```

The `-p` flag causes any parent directories to be created if necessary.

Comment: your folder and subfolder name can be a variable name as well. For example $data_dir='data' and $sub='subdir'. Then we can create directories like mkdir -p $data_dir/$sub

Answer (score 59):

To create multiple sub-folders

```
mkdir -p parentfolder/{subfolder1,subfolder2,subfolder3}
```

Answer (score 34):

FWIW,

Poor mans security folder (to protect a public shared folder from little prying eyes ;) )

```
mkdir -p {0..9}/{0..9}/{0..9}/{0..9}
```

Now you can put your files in a pin numbered folder. Not exactly waterproof, but it's a barrier for the youngest.

Comment: lol that's cute

Comment: I upvote this because it made my day (lol) and also learned me something new, thanks :D

Comment: So nice! But a bash rich man can break it by using a command like `du -h --max-depth=4 | sort -hr`!