# How can I make a new folder with a subfolder using a single linux command?

Tags: linux

I am trying to create a new folder, which has a subfolder inside it.  The new folder is being created in a folder that already exists

I am running the following command:

`mkdir /mobiledata/Google/Tests/NEW_FOLDER/NEW_SUBFOLDER/`

I get an error

`cannot create directory ’/mobiledata/Google/Tests/NEW_FOLDER/NEW_SUBFOLDER/: No such file or directory`

I think what this means is that when I create `NEW_SUBFOLDER/`, the command looks for its parent `NEW_FOLDER` and rejects the command because `NEW_FOLDER` doesn't exist yet.

Is there anyway for me to run a command that creates the new folder first, then the subfolder?  Or another solution?

Thanks.

Comment: [How to create nonexistent subdirectories recursively using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1731767/608639), [Bash mkdir and subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9242163/608639), and friends. I don't think you should ask this question on other sites. It is equally poor on all sites in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 3):

```
mkdir -p new_folder/with_a_subfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

`mkdir` will create as many directories as it can with `-p` switch.

```
$ mkdir -p mobiledata/Google/Tests/NEW_FOLDER/NEW_SUBFOLDER/
$ find mobiledata/
mobiledata/
mobiledata/Google
mobiledata/Google/Tests
mobiledata/Google/Tests/NEW_FOLDER
mobiledata/Google/Tests/NEW_FOLDER/NEW_SUBFOLDER
```

From the manual:

```
   -p, --parents
          no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Comment: why is this a bad q?

Comment: @jww that's going to happen, but why not helping the poor sod?

Comment: @ZakS that's a fine question but it should be on Superuser instead (don't you worry it'll move automatically on close IIRC)

Comment: No, that's only for easy questions. Also consider researching `man mkdir`